# How to Implement Popup Menu Similar to That Used in Magit

Tags: magit, popup

## Question

I would like to create user interface in form of *popup menu*, *popup menu
similar to that used in Magit*.

### Features

#### Definition of Popup

*Popup* in context of this question means little temporary window that
contains collection of menu items so that user can select one and only one
of these items.

#### Position on the Screen

The popup is allowed to appear in any part of the screen, but it's desirable
that it should be quite obvious and thus it should appear beside currently
active window.

#### Contents of Popup Buffer

Items should be displayed in form of pretty table. *Pretty* is context of
the question means visually appealing, this effect can be most easily
achieved by putting menu items into straight rows, see
`complete--insert-string` for example. This paragraph serves for additional
clarification, you can do it in your own way, this won't render your answer
incorrect.

#### Selection of Menu Item

The selection is expected to be performed by a single key-pressing or,
optionally with a mouse (although it's not that important so answers
containing propositions that don't support mouse are legal). If you propose
solution that supports mouse, please note that user should be able to select
a menu item in an intuitive way, that is, by left-button clicking on desired
choice.

N.B. mouse can be used in many ways and alternative ways to indicate
a choice are also welcomed.

#### Elimination of Popup

Once user has selected a menu item in a way described above, the buffer and
thus its window should be eliminated from view as well as killed. The window
that has been active before invocation of the popup menu should get focus
(that is, become active) again.

#### Returned Value and Arguments

Preferably, this consequence of actions should result in a Lisp object
returned. The Lisp object can be either:

- `nil` — this indicates that user has aborted the popup menu either by
  pressing <kbd>C-g</kbd> or in some other way †.
- `string` — string (it's allowed to use a symbol) should be `string-equal`
  to one of the strings supplied to the popup menu as collection of actual
  items.

Alternative ways to let the rest of program know user's choice, or,
possibly, its absence, are acceptable. However, if it's not clear how else
it can be performed I ask all answerers improvise and don't ask me for
further clarification of this aspect.

This is all for returned value. As for input parameters, they should at
least include collection of strings which represent possible choices (that
is, menu items).

### Acceptable Answers

Expected answer can be of the following forms:

- Sufficient code snippet that allows educated reader to write function like
  that described above; it's not expected or necessary to write entire
  working function. However, to avoid uncertainty (can considerable parts of
  code be omitted?), I should note that missing parts of the snippet should
  be described in textual component of answer.
- A link to existing library that implements similar functionality. To avoid
  uncertainty, I should note that *similar* in our case means that the
  library can be used to create *popup* (see definition above) that has at
  least 2 or 3 features described above. If proposed library is different to
  the point where the previously stated condition cannot be met, each such
  case will be judged independently and will be always upvoted if OP deems
  it useful.
- Description of built-in Emacs functions or third-party ones that can be
  used to implement any feature described in section «Features», see
  above. To avoid uncertainty, please state clearly how your answer can be
  useful for future readers who want to implement *popup*, *popup menu
  similar to that used in Magit*.

---

† Alternative ways to abort the popup menu may include the following (but
not limited to these):

- clicking outside of popup menu window;
- killing of buffer containing the popup without making a choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`magit-popup` has it's [own manual](http://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup)! But unless you actually want to set arguments in the popup which are then passed to the invoked action, you are probably better off using [`hydra`](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) instead.

Also note that I don't intend to further develop `magit-popup`. Instead I will write a similar package from scratch. There's just to much accidental complexity in the current implementation. (But that doesn't mean that `magit-popup` will simply vanish. It likely won't see many new features, but if the current implementation does what you want, then why not use it?)

Or since you too want to do it "from scratch", have a look at `read-char-choice` and go from there. To implement the visual part have a look at `lv` which is part of the hydra repository.

Comment: For other readers: Note that @tarsius has followed through and written that replacement for `magit-popup`.  The new package is called `transient`, and this is what is used in current versions of `magit`.  See https://magit.vc/manual/transient/ for documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Hydras are pretty simple to write:

```cl
(defhydra hydra-launcher (:color blue :columns 2)
   "Launch"
   ("h" man "man")
   ("r" (browse-url "http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/") "reddit")
   ("w" (browse-url "http://www.emacswiki.org/") "emacswiki")
   ("s" shell "shell")
   ("q" nil "cancel"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'hydra-launcher/body)
```

Hydra is a keyboard-centric interface, and in its basic form, it's not
harder than `easy-menu-define` (built-in).  And it's quite extensible
if you want to make it do more complex things.

Just look at this twittering interface, the bottom window is a custom Hydra, not much harder to write than the one above:

[image: hydra-twittering.png]

The code for this is available on [the wiki](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra/wiki/Twittering), along with a lot more examples.

Comment: Great, I'll certainly find time to learn more about this thing!

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in looking at the package `makey`. It is intended to provide similar functionality as `magit-popup`, and it is a fork of the predecessor of `magit-popup` (`magit-key-mode`, mentionned in the comment) from when it was not yet a package available separately from `magit`.

Let me also mention `discover` : that is an example of how to use `makey` (and also its raison d'être). That package is meant to help newcomers discover emacs bindings.

---

**References**

- https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/discoverel-discover-emacs-context-menus : description of `makey` and `discover` by its author.
- https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1716 : this is (apparently) when `magit-popup` was made into its own package.

Comment: @Mark I am not quite sure why you accepted this answer. It does not at all mention small building blocks, which, if I remember correctly, is what you were after. It's also isn't not correct: makey isn't a fork of magit-popup, it's a fork of its predecessor magit-key-mode. It inherits most of the deficits that have since been addressed in magit-popup. So you are much better of using magit-popup or hydra (or writing your own).

Comment: @tarsius Judging the correctness of an answer can be hard. If you know it isn't correct, feel free to edit it. I did an edit, I'm still not 100% sure it is correct now. I also didn't mention the "deficits" it inherits because I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've found an idiom that can be used to create a window
at the bottom (or indeed anywhere) of currently active window. This itself
has effect of temporary, auxiliary window:

```
(let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*Name of Buffer*")))
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (with-current-buffer-window
     ;; buffer or name
     buffer
     ;; action (for `display-buffer')
     (cons 'display-buffer-below-selected
           '((window-height . fit-window-to-buffer)
             (preserve-size . (nil . t))))
     ;; quit-function
     (lambda (window _value)
       (with-selected-window window
         (unwind-protect
             ;; code that gets user input
           (when (window-live-p window)
             (quit-restore-window window 'kill)))))
     ;; Here we generate the popup buffer.
     (setq cursor-type nil)
     ;; …
     )))
```

You can play a bit with `action` argument of `with-current-buffer-window` if
you want the popup to appear in different part of the screen.

Quit function is described in doc-string of `with-current-buffer-window`, it
can be used to get input from user. As @tarsius suggested,
`read-char-choice` is a good candidate for experimenting.

The popup buffer itself can be generated just like any other buffer. I'm
still thinking of buttons there, because user could use his mouse to select
an item in the popup menu, not just keyboard. However, this requires
additional effort if you want to do it well.

If your popup is a bit ad-hoc and you won't need it more than once, you can
get away with this solution. Also, take a look at
`completion--insert-strings`. I found it quite useful as an example of how to
generate pretty rows of menu items, you can even use it unaltered if you
don't need something special.

Comment: I think maybe the question you have in your head is good; the question you wrote down is rather unclear, I don't see how anyone could have known you were after an answer like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 3rd-party solution, using [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

- Your code pops up a window with the candidates arranged neatly as a
  menu.  For how, see below.
- You prefix each menu item with a unique character.  E.g.,
  a, b, c... or 1, 2, 3...  The user hits the char to choose the item.
- You bind a few variables around a call to `completing-read`.
  You pass it a list of your menu items.  You optionally specify one
  of the items to be the default, chosen if the user just hits `RET`.

  The variable bindings tell `completing-read` to:

  - Show each menu item on a separate row
  - Show the menu immediately
  - Update it immediately when a user hits a key
  - Return immediately, if the user input matches only one item
  - Show the default choice in the prompt.
- You can make the menu items as fancy as you want (not shown).

  - faces
  - images
  - annotations
  - multiple lines per item
  - `mouse-3` popup menu, to do anything with the item

```el
(defvar my-menu '(("a: Alpha It"   . alpha-action)
                  ("b: Beta It"    . beta-action)
                  ("c: Gamma It"   . gamma-action)
                  ("d: Delta It"   . delta-action)
                  ("e: Epsilon It" . epsilon-action)
                  ("f: Zeta It"    . zeta-action)
                  ("g: Eta It"     . eta-action)
                  ("h: Theta It"   . theta-action)
                  ("i: Iota It"    . iota-action)
                  ("j: Kappa It"   . kappa-action)
                  ("k: Lambda It"  . lambda-action)))

(defun my-popup ()
  "Pop up my menu.
User can hit just the first char of a menu item to choose it.
Or s?he can click it with `mouse-1' or `mouse-2' to select it.
Or s?he can hit RET immediately to select the default item."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((icicle-Completions-max-columns               1)
         (icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag       t)
         (icicle-incremental-completion-delay          0.01)
         (icicle-top-level-when-sole-completion-flag   t)
         (icicle-top-level-when-sole-completion-delay  0.01)
         (icicle-default-value                         t)
         (icicle-show-Completions-help-flag            nil)
         (choice  (completing-read "Choose: " my-menu nil t nil nil
                                   "b: Beta It")) ; The default item.
         (action  (cdr (assoc choice my-menu))))

    ;; Here, you would invoke the ACTION: (funcall action).
    ;; This message just shows which ACTION would be invoked.
    (message "ACTION chosen: %S" action) (sit-for 2)))
```

You can also create truly [multiple-choice
menus](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multiple-Choice_Menus),
that is, menus where a user can choose multiple items at the same
time (choose a subset of the possible choices).

Answer (score 0):

[Guide-Key](https://github.com/kai2nenobu/guide-key) work nice for me for all configured prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Drew's answer (Icicles), with modifications to separate menu implementation from menu data - so multiple menu's could be defined, each with their own: (content, prompt, default).

This optionally uses ivy (when available), which has more advanced features such as being able to activate items while keeping the menu open.

Generic popup.

```el
(defun custom-popup (prompt default-index content)
  "Pop up menu
Takes args: prompt, default-index, content).
Where the content is any number of (string, function) pairs,
each representing a menu item."
  (cond
   ;; Ivy (optional)
   ((fboundp 'ivy-read)
    (ivy-read
     prompt content
     :preselect
     (cond
      ((= default-index -1)
       nil)
      (t
       default-index))
     :require-match t
     :action
     (lambda (x)
       (pcase-let ((`(,_text . ,action) x))
         (funcall action)))
     :caller #'custom-popup))

   ;; Fallback to completing read.
   (t
    (let ((choice
           (funcall completing-read-function
                    prompt
                    content
                    nil
                    t
                    nil
                    nil
                    (nth default-index content))))
      (pcase-let ((`(,_text . ,action) (assoc choice content)))
        (funcall action))))))
```

Example use, assign some actions to the f12 key:

```el
(defvar my-global-utility-menu-def
  ;; (content, prompt, default_index)
  '(("Emacs REPL" . ielm)
    ("Spell Check" . ispell-buffer)
    ("Delete Trailing Space In Buffer" . delete-trailing-whitespace)
    ("Emacs Edit Init" . (lambda () (find-file user-init-file)))))

(defun my-global-utility-popup ()
  "Pop up my menu. Hit RET immediately to select the default item."
  (interactive)
  (custom-popup "Select: " 1 my-global-utility-menu-def))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'my-global-utility-popup)
```