# How to NOT sort icicles menu output?

Tags: completion, sorting, icicles

Using an icicles menu with emacs 26.1, I'm now having the menu sorted.

The menu used to be unsorted (items appeared in the order they were given). In the previous version of emacs they were unsorted.

How can I call the menu so it keeps the items unsorted?

See: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38752/2418

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop "completing-read" / "ivy-completing-read" from sorting?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41801/how-to-stop-completing-read-ivy-completing-read-from-sorting)

Comment: It's not at all a duplicate of that question. One was explicitly about Icicles, the other explicitly about Ivy. There is nothing in common between how/when/why sorting is done in the two cases. But the question should be closed anyway, as you clearly really wanted to ask about Ivy, not Icicles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to be more precise in your description.  I can't repro the problem, except that completion-candidate sorting is on by default.

That is, the default value of option [**`icicle-sort-comparer`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-sort-comparer) is `icicle-case-string-less-p`: sort alphabetically, respecting `completion-ignore-case`.

As always, you can change the sort order on the fly, including turning sorting *off*, using **`C-,`**.  And you can customize option `icicle-sort-comparer` to turn sorting off by default.

And (more relevant here, perhaps) you can *bind* `icicle-sort-comparer` in any command you write, to get the kind of default sorting (including not sorting) you want.  Just bind it to `nil` to turn sorting off by default for that command. (Users of the command can still use `C-,` to change the sort order on the fly.)

Try to provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem you see, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (or at least show the values of Icicles options you might have customized).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I'm not all that experienced and it turns out `icy-mode` wasn't even enabled. instead ivy mode was overwriting my `completing-read`. I've since solved the issue and closed this as a duplicate.