# How to stop "completing-read" / "ivy-completing-read" from sorting?

Tags: ivy

Recently, when using Ivy and calling `completing-read`,
my output is being sorted (instead of showing up in the order passed in).

How can I prevent sorting the input to `completing-read` when using Ivy?

Answer (score 3):

You need your completion-table to tell the completion-UI not to perform sorting (typically because the completion-table already arranges for its own sorting to take place).

See `C-h f completion-metadata`.  Here's an example:

```
(let* ((presorted-completions ...)
      (completion-table
       (lambda (string pred action)
         (if (eq action 'metadata)
             '(metadata (display-sort-function . identity)
                        (cycle-sort-function . identity))
           (complete-with-action
            action presorted-completions string pred))))
  (completing-read "Prompt" completion-table))
```

Comment: This stops `ivy` from being used, is there a general way to handle this so ivy keeps working?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in ivy that you might like to report.

Comment: @ideasman42 Stefan's answer works with Ivy. How is it not working for you? If Ivy still performs unwanted sorting, customise `ivy-sort-functions-alist`. See also https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/1611.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting can be disabled by setting `(ivy-sort-functions-alist nil)`, in the scope you're using `completing-read` (so as not to change defaults everywhere).

See this [complete example](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38752/2418).

Comment: You don't need to set the entire `ivy-sort-functions-alist` to `nil`, only the the entries corresponding to the callers of `completing-read`.