# How to use ivy to navigate named locations of a buffer?

Tags: ivy, completing-read

Given a list of `(point-number . title-text)`, how can ivy be used to show this in a list in `ivy`?

I have code which uses `completing-read` to do this ([see link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35033/2418)).
This can use `ivy` since it extends `completing-read` however it doesn't seem to support all of `ivy`'s features.

For example `ivy-next-line-and-call` and `ivy-previous-line-and-call` don't work.

How can ivy be used directly to navigate sections in a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have code which uses `completing-read` to do this

Ivy's analogue to `completing-read` is the function `ivy-read`, whose operation is described in its docstring and the Ivy User Manual under [`(info "(ivy) API")`](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#api).

> Given a list of `(point-number . title-text)`, how can ivy be used to show this in a list in `ivy`?

Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```el
(defun my-ivy-location (locations)
  "Goto one of LOCATIONS, using Ivy for completion.
LOCATIONS is a list of (POS . LABEL), where POS is a candidate
buffer position and LABEL is a string describing POS for the
purpose of completion."
  (ivy-read "Goto location: " (mapcar #'cdr locations)
            :require-match t
            :action (lambda (label)
                      (let ((pos (car (rassoc label locations))))
                        (when pos (goto-char pos))))
            :caller #'my-ivy-location))
```

Note that Ivy:

- prefers using the `:action` callback rather than the return value of `ivy-read` to operate on the selected candidate(s); and
- identifies the current completion command using the `:caller` property.

Depending on how you populate the `LOCATIONS` alist, it may be preferable to flip the order of its car and cdr, so that both built-in and Ivy completion functions can operate on it more naturally as a "completion table" (see [`(info "(elisp) Basic Completion")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Basic-Completion.html#index-completion-table-1484)):

```el
(defun my-ivy-location-r (locations)
  "Goto one of LOCATIONS, using Ivy for completion.
LOCATIONS is a list of (LABEL . POS), where POS is a candidate
buffer position and LABEL is a string describing POS for the
purpose of completion."
  (ivy-read "Goto location: " locations
            :require-match t
            :action (lambda (location)
                      (let ((pos (cdr-safe location)))
                        (when pos (goto-char pos))))
            :caller #'my-ivy-location-r))
```

> How can ivy be used directly to navigate sections in a document?

[Counsel](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#counsel-commands) is a library of handy utilities provided alongside and implemented using the Ivy API. Perhaps some of the following may also be of interest to you:

- `counsel-imenu` (jumping to buffer sections detected by [imenu](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Imenu.html))
- `counsel-mark-ring` (jumping to buffer locations stored in the [mark ring](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html))
- `counsel-register` (jumping to buffer locations stored in [registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html))